# parsing JSON output using google's gson in java

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

I am new to JSON output, I am using Gson parser to parse the output.

I just want the name of the car and code of the truck from the output, when i parse i get the car name with quotes as output, I remove the quotes with string replace, am I parsing the values correctly?

```
JsonElement jelement = new JsonParser().parse(json);
JsonObject carobject= jelement.getAsJsonObject();
carobject= carobject.getAsJsonObject("Car");
String car = carobject.get("name").toString();
out.println("Car Name:"+car);
```

JSON output:

```
{
        "messages": [
            "For a complete list use showall=true to display 'intersection' element in the Mask"
        ],
        "Mask": {
            "NJS": "120950170151015",
            "section": [
                {
                    "NJS": "120950170151015"
                },
                {
                    "NJS": "120950170151016"
                },
                {
                    "NJS": "120950170151019"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Car": {
            "NJS": "12095",
            "name": "Audi"
        },
        "Truck": {
            "NJS": "12",
            "code": "TL",
            "name": "TLTRUCK"
        },
        "status": "OK",
        "executionTime": "13"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using general purpose `toString()` method, you should use Gson's specific `getAsString()` method. See Gson API documentation [here](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/index.html).

Buy the way, you may want to make your code clearer, like this:

```
JsonObject rootObject = new JsonParser().parse(json).getAsJsonObject();
JsonObject carObject = rootObject.getAsJsonObject("Car");
String carName = carObject.get("name").getAsString();
```